# Django Storage Backend for S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm looking for a good Django custom storage backend for use with Amazon S3.

I've been googling around and found a lot of blog posts with code snippets or half-baked gist.github.com one-off jobs. But I can't seem to find a solid, well-tested one.

Is there a widely accepted standard Amazon S3 Django custom storage backend out there? It doesn't particularly matter to me what Python backend library it uses--i.e., either `S3.py` or `boto` are fine.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you checked out [django-storages](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/)?  I would lean towards the boto library as I have had good experiences with boto.

Comment: Cool. This is exactly what I was looking for: https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/wiki/S3Storage

Comment: Documentation can be found here: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html